# Reading a field of type Date by a scanner

Tags: java, date, methods, java.util.scanner, bluej

```
   private Date startDate;


 public void readData(Scanner scanner)
    {

       // String dates = DateUtil.convertDateToShortString(startDate); 
        dates = scanner.next();

    }
```

How can I read the field startDate of type date by the scanner, I have tried to convert the field to a string and the read it by the scanner but i does not work

Comment: Well what does the *input* look like? Assuming this is in a file, what does the file look like? There are any number of potential representations.

Comment: 000005, TF-68670, AB-312172, Fri Jan 04 00:00:00 GMT 2013, 2

Comment: That's a really ugly format to parse :( Still, it's doable. You probably need to set your scanner to use `,` as the token separator, then use SimpleDateFormat to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the field in as a `String` from the `Scanner` object, then use a `SimpleDateFormat` to parse the string.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.TimeZone;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;

public class DataReader
{
    private Date startDate;

    // format to match Fri Jan 04 00:00:00 GMT 2013
    private SimpleDateFormat inDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy");
    private SimpleDateFormat outDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss z");

    public DataReader() {
        outDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    }

    public String formatStartDate() {
        return outDateFormat.format(this.startDate);
    }

    public void readData(Scanner scanner) {
        String token1 = scanner.next();
        String token2 = scanner.next();
        String token3 = scanner.next();
        String dateToken = scanner.next();
        String token5 = scanner.next();

        System.out.println("Scanned Date Token: " + dateToken);

        try {
            startDate = inDateFormat.parse(dateToken);
        }
        catch (ParseException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "000005, TF-68670, AB-312172, Fri Jan 04 00:00:00 GMT 2013, 2";
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(data);
        scanner.useDelimiter(", ");

        DataReader dr = new DataReader();
        dr.readData(scanner);

        System.out.println("Start Date: " + dr.formatStartDate());
    }
}
```

Here's how the output looks in BlueJ's terminal window:

[image: Scanned Date output]

A couple of things to note:

- I created the `Scanner` object using a simple `String` for input in the main method.  Your code will need to get input from a different source.
- I used different `SimpleDateFormat` objects for parsing the input and formatting the output. This was so you could see the difference, and because Java's simple `Date` objects don't store a time zone.  You have to explicitly set the time zone on the `SimpleDateFormat` used to format output (see the class constructor).